# Passing a filename via a variable to tar from within PHP?

Tags: php, exec, tar

I am trying to ultimately extract some files from a tar archive within PHP, however my simple test script is failing at the first part, which was to simply list the files in the archive.

Is there any reason why this test script fails?

What I see output is:

```
> -sh-3.2$ php showfile.php /var/www/vhosts/smartphonesoft.com/httpdocs/fred/epf/itunes20100825.tbz
> tar: Old option `f' requires an
> argument. Try `tar --help' or `tar
> --usage' for more information.
```

My simple PHP script is:

```
<?php 
foreach (glob("/var/www/vhosts/smartphonesoft.com/httpdocs/fred/epf/itunes*.tbz") as $file) {
 }
$path_parts = pathinfo($file);
$tarfile = $path_parts['filename'];
echo $file . "\n";
exec('tar tvf $file',$ret);

?>
```

Comment: Look at what you are sending to the tar file; then try replicating that on the command line.

Comment: I don't know PHP that well, but what is this script going to do if you have unusual characters in the filenames such as spaces or hyphens ("-")

And what is $tarfile supposed to be?  You don't refer to that variable anywhere after assigning it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have badly placen the parenthesis, ({ }), and bad quotes inside the exec() function:

```
<?php 
foreach (glob("/var/www/vhosts/smartphonesoft.com/httpdocs/fred/epf/itunes*.tbz") as $file) {

$path_parts = pathinfo($file);
$tarfile = $path_parts['filename'];
echo $file . "\n";
exec("tar tvf $file",$ret);

}
```

?>

(using ' quotes does NOT substitute the variable `$file` inside the string for the file you meant.)

EDIT: according to Frxstrem's comment, never forget to escape the filename (in case it contains for example spaces, the above code won't work).

```
exec("tar tvf ".escapeshellarg($file), $ret);
```

Comment: escaping is important to remember - you should therefore use `"tar tvf ".escapeshellarg($file)` instead

Comment: thanks, there will only be one file there that matches that particular string, hence the parenthesis placement.

Comment: @kitenski, in that case, do not use empty statement, just put break; between the {} brackes.